# Repository (Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository) does not accept Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpstan

When upgrading doctrine/persistence from 1.0 to 1.3 I encountered a problem with static code analysis.

```
Repository (Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository) does not accept                    
         Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository.
```

The problem is with this

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Appbundle\Repository\Company;

class CompanyRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    private $entityRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProfileRepository
     */
    private $profileRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->entityRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(Company::class);
    }
```

The code works as getRepository reuturns EntityRepository but return type of getReposiry is ObjectRepository and is not compatible. 
Worked with version 1.0. Anyone got idea what it might be?

Comment: What version of PHPStan and phpstan-doctrine do you have?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok so i found out it is due to Doctrine changing namespaces. It is a reported bug.

https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/7997 
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/7953

Answer (score 0):

This error is correct. `EntityManagerInterface` inherits `getRepository` method from `ObjectManager` interface, where [`ObjectRepository` is typehinted](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/persistence/1.0/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager.html#method_getRepository).

So you can't rely on `EntityRepository` to be returned from the method as the implementation can choose to return just `ObjectRepository`.

You should probably typehint for something else, like `EntityManager` instead.

Comment: EntityManager and EntityRepository are two quite different things. 
I found out that it is a know but that was done in Doctrine/Persistence version 1.3

Comment: I meant you should typehint EntityManager instead of EntityManagerInterface.

Comment: Funny thing. EntityManager doesn't accept EntityManagerInterface. eg. (Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager) does not accept Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I use `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` everywhere and it works.